# Como imprimir el resultado de una busqueda en SQL en un form Html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

tengo el formato de busqueda que se ve mas abajo y en el me piden buscar la informacion de la base de datos por una de 3 variables
[image: Buscar]

para realizar la consulta utilice un switch para identificar como lo estan buscando y cual es el resultado que debe almacenar, como se puede ver en el codigo:

```
<?php

//inicio de conexion y verificacion de errores//    
    $con = mysqli_connect ("localhost" , "root" , "");

    if (!$con) 
    {
        echo 'No conecta al servidor';
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'estrella'))
    {
        echo 'No conecta a base de datos';
    }

    //Recupera valor de busqueda//
    $Bcedula = $_GET['Bcedula'];
    $Blocal = $_GET['Blocal'];
    $Bcontrato = $_GET['Bcontrato'];

    $min_length =3;
    //funcion busqueda por cedula//

    switch (true) 
    {
        case (strlen($Bcedula) >= $min_length):
        $Bcedula = htmlspecialchars($Bcedula);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Ncedula LIKE '%".$Bcedula."%')");
        break;

        case (strlen($Blocal) >= $min_length):
        $Blocal = htmlspecialchars($Blocal);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Nlocal LIKE '%".$Blocal."%')");

        case (strlen($Bcontrato) >= $min_length):
        $Bcontrato = htmlspecialchars($Bcontrato);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Ncontrato LIKE '%".$Bcontrato."%')");

        default: 
            echo 'error dato no encontrado';
            break;
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($rawresults) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($rawresults)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo("<p> Contrato, Cedula, Nombres, Apellidos, Local, Nit, CC, Direccion, Telefono, Valor total, Fecha inicio, N. Cuoas.</p></br>"); 
                echo "<p>" .$results['Ncontrato'].", ".$results['Ncedula'].", ".$results['Nombre1']." ".$results['Nombre2']." ".$results['Apellido1']." ".$results['Apellido2'].", ".$results['Nlocal'].", ".$results['Nnit'].", ".$results['Ncamara'].", ".$results['Direccion'].", ".$results['Telefono'].", ".$results['Vcontrato'].", ".$results['Vfechainicio'].", ".$results['Vcuotas'].                 
                "</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
             echo mysqli_error($con);
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }



?>
```

la idea es que los resultados aparezcan en el cuadro grande que se ven abajo como una tabla, pero lastimosamente lo que esto obteniendo es esto:

[image: Resultado no deseado]

la informacion es correcta pero aparece en una pagina aparte, y no se como hacer que imprima en el espacio que necesito

el HTML se ve mas o menos asi

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Busqueda</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#Table_01 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-image: url(images/Busqueda.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Busqueda.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1109" height="471" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <form method="get" action="busqueda.php">
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Bcedula"></td>
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Nlocal"></td>
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Bcontrato"></td>
    </form>

    <form mehod="post" action="busqueda.php">
            <input style="width:912px; height:283" type="search" name="Rbusqueda">      
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

les agradezco de antemano me puedan ayudar porque llevo ya demasiado varado en esto

Comment: Pd. si hay alguna manera mas eficiente de hacer algo de lo que ya hice y no la conozco sientanse en la libertad de explicarme asi no me ayude a solucionar el problema directamente... siempre es bueno aprender algo nuevo

Comment: Necesitas enviar de nuevo la página completa con todo y formulario (otra vez) pero abajo lo que se busco, esa sería una forma muy precaria de hacerlo pero funciona. Hoy en día se utiliza AJAX para cumplir con lo que estas pidiendo.

Comment: LOL, estas usando tablas para modelar? Quién te está enseñando? Eso se usaba en los 90's. Me tomaré el momento para darte una mejor propuesta

Comment: hombre es para un trabajo para la universidad y voy en 4to semestre... yo supongo que deben haber nuevas cosas pero la verdad esto es lo que apenas estoy aprendiendo a manejar... pero igual gracias por tu ayuda y por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Dado a que estás usando información vieja por que estás modelando con tablas, te daré una intro a algo más comercial (Pero no tan potente como React.js o Angular ) con Jquery y Bootstrap, conseguirás más potencial y más ofertas laborales si estas buscando eso, si empiezas a adentrarte a Javascript y CSS3. Te dejo un snippet con el código HTML y Javascript, no funciona por que no estamos en tu servidor, pero debería funcionar cuando lo implementes allá.

Recuerda que esto funciona con HTML5 por lo que debes de poner los tags y metas correspondientes. Puedes conocer más de modelado y presentación de aplicaciones con [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp) y [Jquery](https://jquery.com/)

Tu código PHP ya funciona y ese no lo tocaremos, con esto deberías conseguir lo que necesitas, por mucho podrías cambiar

```
$Bcedula = $_GET['Bcedula'];
$Blocal = $_GET['Blocal'];
$Bcontrato = $_GET['Bcontrato'];
```

Por

```
$Bcedula = $_REQUEST['Bcedula'];
$Blocal = $_REQUEST['Blocal'];
$Bcontrato = $_REQUEST['Bcontrato'];
```

Que te resulte, saludos

```js
//Cuando el DOM haya cargado
$( ()=> {
  
  //Agregar un listener a la clase search (al boton de la lupa) para cuando se le de click
  $(document).on('click', '.search',function(){
      
      //Capturar el valor más de input más cercano al botón que se dió click
      const val = $(this).parents('.input-group').find('input').val();
      console.log( val );
      
      //Declaramos un objeto que nos ayudará a darle forma a la petición AJAX
      const ajax = {};
      
      //Esta será la ruta a donde irá la petición
      ajax.url = 'busqueda.php';
      
      //Será una petición GET, te recomiendo ahondes en el tema de metodos de petición por que esto se usa en API´s modernas
      ajax.method = 'GET';
      
      //Vamos a mandar el valor que capturamos en el input
      ajax.data = { val };
      
      //Cuando el backend nos responda vamos a poner todo lo que respondió en el espacio de abajo
      ajax.success = function( respuesta ){
        $('.jumbotron').empty().html( respuesta );
      };
      
      //Hacemos la petición
      $.ajax( ajax );
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por No. de cédula">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-success search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por No. de local">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-success search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por No. de contrato">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-success search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="jumbotron">
  
  </div>
</div>
```